# No Wi-Fi adapter found after installing Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu

“No Wi-Fi adapter found” is the message I got after installing `Ubuntu 17.10`.

With the following command line `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`, I got the following message. How could I fix that issue?

[image: output]

### UPDATE

Here is the error if I play in the settings : [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TQAC.png)

Comment: Please post all relevant text information *as* *text*.

Comment: What do you suggest? All that text is on the issuing computer.

Comment: How, exactly, is that an issue? Are you saying that the machine that has the problem has absolutely no Internet connectivity (not even through Ethernet)? because you didn’t say that in the question. Even if you can’t copy the text into your question on the machine with the problem, you can dump it into a file, put it on a flash drive, and sneakernet it to the machine that has connectivity. Worst case, you could transcribe it manually.

Comment: In fact, I do not have Ethernet wire in my bedroom.